# How to storage speed-time data of per second on my DB?

Tags: database, core-data

I have a speed-time data per second follow as,

myfile.txt

08 25 45 78 78 80 100 110 110 100 100 100...120

1s 2s 3s 4s 5s 6s 7s  8s  9s  10s 11s 12s...60slike this.

and I have to storage speed-time data of per second on my Database? How can I do? 
I am waiting your suggestions and ideas..
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Seems simple enough. Just parse the string and store it in the database.

As for parsing you could split the lines of the text file like this:

```
NSArray *lines = [fileText componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];
```

To get the data from the first line:

```
NSArray *speeds = [firstLine componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
```

This will be strings, but you can most likely convert them into a number with a method like `floatValue`.

As for storing in the database, your Core Data model would look something like this:

```
Race < ------ >> SpeedData
```

where SpeedData contains fields like `second` and `speed`.

For more basic questions of how to make Core Data work, find a tutorial or read the documentation.

Comment: Firstly Thanks for your interested. I can parse this file and I can storage per second as speed but overall I have speed-time data of 24 hour or maybe 1 year and It will be million data on Database so It seems like complex.. At this point I have one idea. I can storage core data(myfile.txt) as binary(like blob) on Database. Actually it may be basic question for you but I could not find another idea so I asked this question

Comment: To store the text file in core data instead of as a file does not give you any performance advantage. Core Data is fine with millions of entries ;-).